# One to Many to One Model logic

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need help with my model logic. I am trying to recreate an application tracking app that takes in a Candidate instance. Here's my basic model structure:

```
from django.db import models

class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Job(models.Model):
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title


class Application(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    application_date = models.DateField()

    def__str__(self):
        return str(self.job) + ' ' + str(self.candidate)
```

Here are the logic parameters:

- A Candidate can only have one instance, but can have multiple Applications
- An Application for each Candidate can only exist in one Job

Something that would probably result to this API view:

```
# candidate detail
"candidate": {
    # candidate info from model
    "id": 1,
    ...
    "applications": {
        # application 1
        # application 2
    }
}

# application detail
"application": {
    # application info from model
    "id": 1, 
    ... 
    "candidate_id": 1
    "job_id": 1
}

# job detail
"job": {
    # job info from model
    "id": 1, 
    ...
}
```

One thing that was throwing me off was how I would be able to show the list of Applications in each Candidate instance and how it relates to the Application model. I don't know how to even explain in the title(and if it's even correct), but my thinking is ONE candidate can have MANY applications but has to be ONE(unique candidate) for each job. I really appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction.

EDIT: Also, how would additional applications can be made by the same Candidate if it has to be unique? This model is driving me crazy. Please help.

Comment: Do you need a M2M in `Job` here? Wouldn't using FK work the same here cause it's plural as well, maybe try supplying `unique=True` here. I could be wrong I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For the first look - and I'm not sure if I udnertstand your problem correctly - you don't need to have candidates field in your Job model.
I would do this: 
1. have Candidate model, just as you have.
2. have Job model, without the candidates field
3. have Application model, just as you have.

With this "A Candidate can only have one instance, but can have multiple Applications" issue is done.
Regarding the other issue "An Application for each Candidate can only exist in one Job" I would handle it in your view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Assuming that I'll be using the Model Serializer, would the logic to check if the Candidate exists in Job before adding work on the serializer? I am not sure how to do the logic check in the views - can you point me to a reference? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how your API will work. But in some place in your code you will add / create instances for your Application class. If that's the case then:

Comment: you should use a form to enter Applications, eg: `class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):`. In this form class, you can create a clean method:  `def clean(self):` where you can define validation rules, eg: checking if a Job / Candidate pair with the same instances exists yet in your database.